# Recover from failed multisite conversion

Tags: multisite, backup

I'm normally quite the techie (look at my SF account!) but it turns out I know nothing about Wordpress and in doing so have sabotaged my wife's blog.

As a family we have a hosting package through Namecheap who also manage my domains, I'm fine with the whole DNS thing.

They provide web hosting via /public_html and using their cpanel I installed Wordpress in single site mode into a /public_html/*wife's name*

This all went great for months until my daughter asked for a site, I then followed the instructions to convert it to a multisite but something went wrong, after a bit of faffing about with .htaccess I managed to get it working again - except it won't allow for photo upgrades and I still have a more-moody-than-normal teen on my hands.

What I'd really like to do is somehow backup all of my wife's posts, config, photos etc. including the DB, wipe the whole installation, reinstall as multisite and restore it all.

What's the chances of that working and if so what would be my first steps. Again sorry that this seems so amateur, it's really not the kind of thing I normally do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have access to your wife's blog, I would recommend:

- Running a regular WordPress export of the content
- Downloading the entire `/wp-content` directory over FTP

These are the two most important parts of the site - the content and the uploads.  From this, you *should* be able to recreate the site on a clean installation by FTPing the uploads to the server and re-importing her content.

Just to be safe (in case things break again and you need someone to take a hand's on look) do this in a *new* database.  Don't wipe anything, just create a new db and a new folder in your hosting account for the domain.  This way, if a pro needs to get in and re-do things manually, you've still got everything in place.

Comment: Thank you, so the /wp-content includes everything? I thought the actual posts were in the DB?

Comment: The *posts* are in the DB. The uploads, theme, and plugins are in `/wp-content`.  That's why I used 2 bullet points, you need to do both :-)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, so I can just restore the DB into a new one? is there a DB per site? being dim I know sorry, bit late where I am (UK).

Comment: Leave the DB on the server alone. Create a *new* DB for the new site. Use WordPress' built-in export tool to export the content of the old site as an XML file. Then, when the new site is set up, use the WordPress Importer to pull the content in to the new site.

Comment: THANK you, I wasn't even aware of the exporter/importer, really appreciate it.